# Correct form of pronoun I

Tags: pronouns

There is a sentence in my book

> It was **me** that raised the alarm

I am completely  confused with this construction. "I" is used with it but here "me" is placed.

Second confusion is "who" is used for living things but here "that" is used.

Is it grammatically correct? If yes please explain to me.

Comment: What you're saying is that it should be, *"It was **I who** raised the alarm"*?

Comment: You're quite right that "who" is ***only*** used for living things. But here "that" can be used for ***any*** referent. Except that at least some people would say it makes a difference whether the context is a restrictive or non-restrictive clause.

Comment: It's fine with accusative "me". Contrary to common believe, there is no rule of English requiring a nominative form where a pronoun is complement of the verb "be". With personal antecedents, there is a preference for "who" when the relativised element is subject (as in your example) and for the non-_wh_ elsewhere. But it is just a preference: "It was me that raised the alarm" is perfectly grammatical.